# How to ignore the mouse events except the last one in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, mouseevent

See below for code sample, the method **handleMouseDoubleClick** method will take seconds to run and open another layout screen containing buttons and links. End users may click many times on one listed item in the table control and create flood of mouse events, how can I handle the last mouse event only?

```
Table tableControl = (Table) control;
tableControl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
  public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e)
  {
    handleMouseDown(e);
  }

  public void mouseUp(MouseEvent e)
  {
    handleMouseUp(e);
  }

  public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e)
  {
    handleMouseDoubleClick(e);
  }
```

}

Comment: If you ignore `mouseDown();` and `mouseUp();` the users are still able to flood the UI with `MouseEvent` via `mouseDoubleClick();` aren't they?

Answer (score 1):

Create a flag field. Set it to `true` when handler was called. Initialize it with `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check whether your screen is already initialized or not before creating another one.

Answer (score 0):

Set the cursor to hourglass and/or disable the table, resetting these after the new "layout screen" is closed...